# Do you use a salt when encrypting a password or just when hashing a password?

Tags: encryption, password-hashing, salt

A password is used to connect to a database.
This password is kept in a file.
This password (therefore) needs to be encrypted.
A program to access the aforementioned database needs (of course) the password.
Currently the program decrypts the password, uses the password to connect to the aforementioned database.

Is it recommended to use a salt value when encrypting this password?  Or is salting only related to hashing?  Or is salting something that is used with both encryption and hashing.  My understanding is that using a salt in 'one-way' and related to hashing.

Comment: We don't encrypt passwords, we hash them with good password hashing algorithms (Scrypt, Argon2) with random salt per hash additionally server salt called pepper.

Comment: I am writing a program that must decrypt a password, use it, then re-encrypt. So you’re saying I should have code to unhash then rehash the password? I thought hashing was one way.

Comment: Why don't you tell your actual need? There is no unhash, cryptographic hash functions are expect to be one way!

Comment: @kelalaka better?

Comment: There are still problems, 1) why do you encrypt back the password, you still have the encrypted file. 2) how do you store the encryption key?

Comment: @kelalaka I edited the post -- there is a separate program that encrypts the password to be placed in the file.  Why don't we agree to answer the question as it was initially stated -- which, in summary, is whether or not a salt is needed with encryption.  You seem to be getting lost in the weeds.

Comment: Sry to everyone if my question was not initially made clear.

Comment: You did not specify the encryption method, your question still is not clear. Due to Ind-CPA security, we need IV/nonce for block cipher encryption modes like CBC/CTR. What is your encryption method? How you keep or derive the encryption key? Which key derivation do you plan to use? The database password scheme determines the use of salt for the password. Which database are you using? Still, your question has lack of the most important parts for security, See [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html)

Comment: @kelalaka My question has been answered -- see below. Thx

Comment: Then see this [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/86735) and Still, you seem that knows little about encryption.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you -- I'll take a look at this resource.

Comment: Sometimes we DO encrypt passwords - when we need to provide those passwords to third parties to authenticate to access resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salt ( a.k.a $CaCl_2$) is added before hashing to prevent rainbow attacks. So each password will be appended to a unique salt before hashing and if the server is hacked and the hashes are leaked, a hacker will have hard time un-hashing with rainbow tables.

Salting has no use in encryption/decryption because it serves no purpose.

Comment: Thank you. Sry to everyone if my question was not initially made clear.

Comment: Nitpick: salt isn't added to prevent just rainbow table attacks, it's added to prevent a much wider variety of multi-target and time-memory tradeoff attacks, one of which happens to be rainbow tables.

Comment: @SAIPeregrinus Can u give me link that explain how hashing is useful beside preventing  rainbow table attacks

Comment: @AvenDesta: For one example, it also prevents a basic dictionary attack, where you just hash every word in a dictionary (and common names, and often well-known variants, such as substituting `0` for `O`, `1` for `I`, and so on).

Comment: @JerryCoffin how is that different from rainbow dictionary attack?

Comment: Rainbow tables are very different from dictionary tables. They involve a "reduction function" that creates a plaintext when given a hash. They use chains of hash->reduction sequences to store only an initial plaintext and a final hash, allowing for a significant space savings. https://web.archive.org/web/20201109003858/http://kestas.kuliukas.com/RainbowTables/ is a good explanation.